# ¿Como seleccionar solo 1 boton con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo cierta cantidad de botones en un mismo div, como haria para que solo me deje seleccionar solo 1 a la vez? y guardar el valor del button seleccionado?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo realmente no entiendo a que te refieres con *como haria para que solo me deje seleccionar solo 1 a la vez?*

te dejo varios ejemplos de como obtener datos con **jquery**

> NOTA: des habilito los `input[type="checkbox"]` por que creo que necesitas que solo se seleccione uno . si no es el caso el usuario podría seleccionar los 3 `input`.

```js
$(".con-checks").find("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  $(".con-checks").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled",true)
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="con-checks">
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="" value="check 1">
<label for="check1">Check 1</label>

<input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="" value="check 2">
<label for="check2">Check 2</label>

<input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="" value="check 3">
<label for="check3">Check 3</label>
<div>
```

```js
$(".con-radios").find("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="con-radios">
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radios" value="Radio 1">
<label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radios" value="Radio 2">
<label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>

<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radios" value="Radio 3">
<label for="radio3">Radio 3</label>
<div>
```

```js
$(".btns").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btns" type="button" name="button">Boton 1</button>
  <button class="btns" type="button" name="button">Boton 2</button>
  <button class="btns" type="button" name="button">Boton 3</button>
```

Avísame si es lo que necesitas o que cambios le faltan para ayudarte amigo.

Comment: Amigo tu ultima respuesta con los botones me ayudo bastante :) y pues estuve equivocado con la pregunta pero de todas formas me ayudo bastante como obtienes el valor del button ya que lo que quiero hacer es guardar el valor de un button para luego este sea almacenado en un arreglo ya que tengo algunos formularios de botones de solo una seleccion y otros formularios de multiples selecciones de botones a guardar.

Comment: Excelente amigo poder ayudarte recuerda para la próxima especificar mejor para una respuesta mas acorde saludos.